# Write a DAX IF expression that in the instance of a Blank Value has a separate result?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to evaluate on a column against another column in a different table that can only have (3)

```
outcomes (The output result desired) :
A Match = True
Mismatch = False
Blank = Data missing
```

So far I have: (Column is on different table)

```
IF(LOOKUP(Column, Column, Table[Column1])=Table[Column1], "True", "False")
```

This works but I don't know how to have it also evaluate for blank value for a separate output result??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LOOKUPVALUE(), there is no LOOKUP in DAX,
and then another IF. For my understanding you want to look for an empty searchValue

```
IF (
    ISBLANK ( Table1[Column1] ),
    IF (
        LOOKUPVALUE ( Table2[Column], Table2[Column], Table1[Column1] ) = Table1[Column1],
        "True",
        "False"
    ),
    "Data missing"
)
```

If you want to check is blank LOOKUPVALUE-Result then

```
VAR result =
    LOOKUPVALUE ( Table2[Column], Table2[Column], Table1[Column1] )
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( result ),
        "Data Missing",
        IF ( result = Tabelle1[Column1], "true", "false" )
    )
```